# javascript XMLHttpRequest needs controller?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring Boot 2.6.2
Java 11
Thymeleaf

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvva0.png)

My goal is to load navbar.html through javascript when categoryTest.html is opened.
First of all, I add this code to categoryTest.html

```
        <nav class="navbar" includeHTML="navbar.html">
        </nav>
```

And there is the function I wrote

```
    function includeHTML() {
        var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;

        z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
            elmnt = z[i];

            file = elmnt.getAttribute("includeHTML");

            if (file) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
                        if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
                    }
                }
                xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
                xhttp.send();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I start the server and see the result, xhttp.send() is the problem.

But once I add this method to my controller, it works well.

```
    @GetMapping("/navbar.html")
    public ModelAndView navbar(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("navbar");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**Idk why this method is required for this process.**

Comment: Better to use attribute selector `[includeHTML]`

Comment: I know next to nothing about Spring Boot or Thymeleaf but I would assume you could serve those directly from the static directory

Comment: Coming from a .Net background I would presume that your backend is not treating requests to .html as static files and otherwise trying to route it to a controller which fails without that method/function.

Comment: May I ask why you are loading your navbar through JavaScript? Why not just include it in the HTML that Thymeleaf renders?